# I need your help about a list

Tags: python, list

For example, I have a list like ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'D'))

In this list, I want to take elements that form () with 'A' elements.

This means, I want to take elements ('A', 'B') and ('A', 'C')

Not 'A', 'B' or ('C', 'D')

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a conditional list comprehension. I check if `'A'` is in the list and if it is and the content isn't only A (hence the `len` check), then add it to the list.

```
temp = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'D'))
results = [i for i in temp if 'A' in i and len(i) > 1]
print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And I have another question. I could get ('A', 'B') and ('A', 'C'). With this results, can I get 'B' and 'C'? Easily to say, I want to get elements in () form, have 'A' but not 'A' element.

Comment: @mcKim `results = [i[1] for i in temp if 'A' in i and len(i) > 1]` would be the way to go.  If you could mark mine as solution, it'd help a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
l = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'D'))
[x for x in l if type(x) == tuple and 'A' in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through like this:

```
new_lst = []
lst = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'D'))
for i in lst:
    if len(i) > 1 and i[0] == "A":
        new_lst.append(i)

print new_lst
```